# i want to fetch Checked items on a checklistbox into a label

Tags: c#, string, arraylist, checklistbox

```
string acom = AcompList.CheckedItems.ToString();
            Label1.Text = (Pratotxt.Text + "\n" + Tamanhotxt.Text + "\n" + Obstxt.Text + "\n" + acom + "\n" + Mesatxt.Text + "\n" + Enderecotxt.Text);
```

but it's showing this text on the label: System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox+CheckedItemCollection

i used

```
AcompList.CheckedItems.ToString();
 \\doesnt work
string acom = AcompList.GetSelected;
 \\ idk why i even used this one
string acom = AcompList.Items.Cast<string>; 
\\ gives CS0428 error
```

Comment: `CheckedItems` items is a *collection* of items.  you need to iterate the collection and print each item.  Many, many examples here to do that.  With a little more research you could learn to use linq to *join* the selections into a single comma separated string.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp i'm totally new to these concepts, never heard of Linq, started C# few weeks ago ty

Answer (score 0):

Like Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp `CheckedItems` items is a collection of items. You should looping the list of items like this

```
    string checkedItemsText = "";
    
    foreach (object item in AcompList.CheckedItems) 
    //or CheckedIndices if you just want to concat string with checked=true
    { 
        checkedItemsText += item.ToString() + "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where items are added to the Items collection for months.

Load via Items

```cs
MonthsCheckedListBox.Items.AddRange(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames[..^1].ToArray());
```

Or DataSource

```cs
MonthsCheckedListBox.DataSource = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames[..^1].ToList();
```

Language extension to get checked items. Note this can be done w/o an extension but this keeps your code clean.

```cs
public static class CheckedListBoxExtensions
{
    public static List<T> CheckedList<T>(this CheckedListBox sender)
        => sender.Items.Cast<T>()
            .Where((_, index) => sender.GetItemChecked(index))
            .Select(item => item)
            .ToList();
}
```

Usage where the delimiter here is a space, change as you see fit.

```cs
Label1.Text = string.Join(" ", MonthsCheckedListBox.CheckedList<string>());
```

Or

```cs
var results = string.Join(" ", MonthsCheckedListBox.CheckedList<string>());
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(results))
{
    Label1.Text = "No selection";
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = results;
}
```